# Submission of a webpage form using WebBrowser control in C#

Tags: c#, controls, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control

I have seen a lot of posts regarding this particular subject on SO as well as on the web in general and most if not all code is as seen below

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/onsubmit.htm"));
}

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    mshtml.HTMLDocument htmlDoc = null;

    htmlDoc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument) this.webBrowser1.Document;

    if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
    {
        foreach (mshtml.HTMLFormElement form in htmlDoc.forms)
        {
            form.submit();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The code has no errors whatsoever but for the life its not submitting. The sample page that I am using has simple button, what it does, it alerts the selection of the radio button and then submits the form. For some strange reason when the form is submitted via code using the WebBrowser control, the form is submitted but the alert never shows up.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: May I ask why are you trying to do this?

Comment: How did you hook the event, and to what ?

Comment: @Matti, I am trying to automate a login procedure on a internal network which does not have the remember me option.

Comment: @Yochai, I am sorry but I did understand you question.

Comment: @vikramjb: So you're making an entirely new (and very limited) browser just to automate a login? Sounds like more trouble than it's worth. Write it using GreaseMonkey or whatever.

Comment: @Matti, its not about just about logging in. First I am making it so that I can wet mt hands on WPF. Second, once login is done, there are procedures like searching for a ticket based on a ticket number or searching for a ticket based on several filters. And this app is a not a browser, I am using the browser control to load the webpage and extract the data and present it in different interface which is easier for me to use.

Comment: @vikramjb, why not convert the login and whatever other information sources you need to a wcf service?  seems like the most logical solution to me, much better than parsing through html anyway.

Comment: @nathan, the login form is a third party webservice. Simply put the login system is third party login system where the client logs all tickets. I am not comfortable with the usability provided in the ticketing system. I just want to make my life a little easier by logging into the sytem automatically and automating few functionalities like viewing a particular detail. I am also doing this so that I can learn how to work webBrowser control and WPF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would performing a click on the button do what you need it to do?  You will need to add a COM reference to the Microsoft HTML Object Library (which you may already have).  For example, if you load up google into the webbrowser control, this code will place "hello world" into the search box and perform the search:

```
        mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = ((mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)webBrowser1.Document);


         ((mshtml.IHTMLElement)doc.all.item("q")).setAttribute("value", "hello world");
         MessageBox.Show("Clicking I'm feeling lucky button");
        ((mshtml.HTMLInputElement)doc.all.item("btnI")).click();
```

Edit:  I updated the code for the components that the WPF WebBrowser control uses.  Also note that this sometimes throws a script error from google, but that appears to be a timing issue based on some of the ajax calls google has on the home page.

Comment: The All method does not seem to be present in the webBrowser1 control. Am I missing something ?

Comment: The .all property is a member of the .Document member of the webbrowser class.  It has been available since .net 2.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.all(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: I am using webBrowser control in a WPF project and I don't see that method anywhere.Moreove the document property of the webBrowser control seems to be of Object data type.

Comment: I updated the code to use the COM objects that are exposed by the WPF control, I was testing with the WinForms control initially.

Comment: got it John. Made some minor code changes and I was ready to go.

Comment: As of 2021-06-03, buttons don't implement mshtml.IHTMLInputElement and mshtml.IHTMLInputElement doesn't have a click method.

Answer (score 3):

To fix your problem you need to replace line:

```
form.submit();
```

With following code:

```
var children = form as IEnumerable;
var inputs = children.OfType<mshtml.HTMLInputElement>();
var submitButton = inputs.First(i => i.type == "submit");

submitButton.click();
```

This will show alert about user selection and submit form.

Comment: The submit button is a image which calls a JS for submitting the form which is why I did form.submit.

Comment: You can find an image inside form (in the same way as I did with submit button) and then click it. It will help you, in case when script which you mentioned does something more than simply submitting form.

Comment: Oleg your answer was also correct buts since, I tried john's sample first I gave the bounty to him.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a more dirty one-liner working by injecting a JavaScript to submit the form

```
_webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { "document.getElementById('formName').submit()" });
```

That's been working for me when interacting with a site using a lot of JavaScript and button beyond the form.

Comment: A dirty one-line indeed, but it's the only answer on this page that worked for me.