# How to auto submit javascript form

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

There is a search button a a webpage :

```
<td><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td dir="ltr" width="10" height="21"><img src="/global/images/ButtonLeftDove.gif" border="0" alt="" height="21" width="10" /></td><td height="21" align="center" valign="middle" class="ButtonDove" nowrap="nowrap"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('mobjTemplate$ctl01$btnSearch2','')" onmouseover="window.status='Search';return true;" onmouseout="window.status='';return true;">Search</a></td><td dir="ltr" width="10" height="21"><img src="/global/images/ButtonRightDove.gif" border="0" alt="" height="21" width="10" /></td></tr></table></td>
```

**it is calling a javascript function javascript:__doPostBack('mobjTemplate$ctl01$btnSearch2','')**

the java function is as following:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {

    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {

        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;

        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;

        theForm.submit();

    }

}
```

I need to auto click that search button.

I tried this code but it does  not work:

```
HtmlElementCollection elemColl2 = null;
HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser.Document;
elemColl2 = doc.GetElementsByTagName("form");

foreach (HtmlElement elem in elemColl2)
            {
                elem.InvokeMember("submit");
            }
```

How can I do that??

Thanks for help in advance..

Comment: What about the code isn't working? The javascript you posted should work. Why is failing? Can you debug using Firebug or something?

Comment: the java code is from the webpage it is not my code. I am just trying to click search button powered with this piece of java code.

Comment: There's some useful-looking code and examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902006/submission-of-a-webpage-form-using-webbrowser-control-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying to get the anchor (or button) and use .click() on that.  I've just had poor luck using 'submit' on the form itself in javascript in the past (which is what you're doing, through a layer of indirection).

You can use:

```
link.InvokeMember("Click");
```

To click the link once you've gotten it into a variable.

Comment: Can you elaborate or share some sample code?  I was thinking along the same lines, but I don't see a `Click` method on the `HtmlElement` class.  (There's a `Click` event, but no method.)  Do you identify the elements from the document in a different way than with that class?

Comment: I haven't used the WebBrowser much at all, but I've done a lot of JavaScript coding.  I know that there is a JavaScript click method, so I would assume that the C# class would have some means of performing it as well.  My guess is that it would look much like the code you have for submitting the form (i.e. the 'invokeMember' method).

Comment: A quick search confirms that. First result: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479490/click-an-html-link-inside-a-webbrowser-control).  Updated post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason that it's not "submitting" is because the element in the page isn't a form element and doesn't have an associated submit action.  It's an anchor element with some JavaScript in the `href` (which is distasteful to say the least, but it's not your code so don't worry).

(Side note, you keep saying "Java" where you mean "JavaScript."  The two are quite different.)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4953253/328193) to a very similar (though not *exactly* duplicate, so I'm hesitant to vote to close this question) question appears to be a workable solution.  You may need to add a COM reference, which I personally try to avoid unless *absolutely* necessary (but that's just me), but being able to invoke a "click" on the anchor element in question *should* do the trick.  (Assuming the `WebBrowser` control is interpreting the JavaScript on the page correctly.)

Comment: David, you are very right and now I am trying the suggestion in the link. However, I am getting an error: Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument' to 'mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass' at this line: mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = ((mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass)webBrowser1.Document);

Comment: @ValNolav: Are you using WinForms or WPF?  It appears that the answer changed from the former to the latter.  Take a look at earlier code in the answer's revision history: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4953253/revisions  You might not need to use the COM library, if this is the case.  You just need to invoke a "click" on the element.

Comment: I am using a winform. I do not know if it is OK to give the webpage I am working on here is the webpage http://www.sap.com/partners/directories/SearchPartner.epx

Answer (score -1):

You can get the button element with javascript and then call the click event manually.
And... I will rather stop programming like that (I mean calling asp.net ids in javascript. There's so much easier ways to do the same. Eg: a submit button

Comment: I am writing a code in c# and this is just a piece of it. Besides, I do not know javascript.

Comment: @Eric: Modifying the HTML/JavaScript in the document held by the `WebBrowser` control probably isn't a good idea.  Are you confusing this (interacting with a web page fetched from within a `WebBrowser` control) with actually _being_ a web page where he would have control over the rendered markup?

Comment: IF you're using c#, you should use asp.net also. For example a button like <asp:submit>

Comment: with Webbrowser control I manipulated some of the controls on that webpage like selecting options, filling out textbox etc. All I need now to click the search button and complete my search. Nothing more but I cannot do that.I will appreciate sample codes!

Comment: @EricFrick: "IF you're using c#, you should use asp.net also" - Except that he's not doing web development.  He's _consuming_ a web page from within what is likely a WinForms application.  He needs to _interact_ with that web page (which is coming from an external uncontrolled resource), not modify it.

Comment: k, i guess I misunderstood the question then.

Answer (score -1):

Understand the fact that the code you write in C# is going to be executed at the server side. What you actually need is to write a javascript code so that that form get submitted at client side. you can call form.submit when you want to submit the form.

Comment: I think you're mistaking this for actual ASP.NET development.  He appears to be using a WebBrowser control (potentially within a Windows Form) to access a webpage (which happens to be a WebForm, but that's not the concern here).  He's not controlling the markup returned by that server, and all of his code runs in one instance.